# weird hexadecimal representation in python \xhhK

Tags: python, c, hex

Today I was playing a little bit with encoding variables in c style to get easy communication to a necessary c-program.
I read https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html
I know that \x starts 2 digit hex representation but for a few numbers I get:

```
from struct import *
datum=239179
buf = pack(">Q", datum)
buf
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xa6K'
```

What ist \xa6K? \xa6 is the valid form.

Unpacking this variable works totally fine, so it seems a legit way of hex but why? For a similar problem a friend wrote a go-program, which gives him for the same number
00 00 00 00 00 03 a6 4b . Now if we check the hex value of K it is 4b.

tldr;
Why is \xa6K the same as \xa6\x4b ?

Thanks for your help :)

---

Thanks for this solution , i feel a little bit stupid :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct.pack` returns a `str` object (`bytes` in python3).  Strings choose to represent **non-printing characters** using hex codes (`'\xa6'` for instance).  However, the byte corresponding to `'\x4b'` is a printable character, so the string uses that instead.